# GSheet custom query formula

Tags: google-sheets

In a GSheet workbook, I am fetching unique data from a sheet to another in order to create a report.
the input sheet containg in column F the categories and in column L the sections, I needed to get the two variables without duplicates, to do so I could write the following formula:
`=UNIQUE(QUERY(Input!A:L, "SELECT L, F WHERE L IS NOT NULL AND F IS NOT NULL", 0))`

The goal of this report is to show the aggregation per categories and sections that's why I need to add a row at the end of each section and put the section value in the category column.

Here is the expected result:

| Section | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Basic necessities | Flour |
| Basic necessities | Milk |
| Basic necessities | Oil |
| Basic necessities | Basic necessities |
| Beverages | Juice |
| Beverages | Water |
| Beverages | Soda |
| Beverages | Beverages |

I tried many times but in vain, could you please help me in this?

thanks

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),  such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: `The goal of this report is to show` Would you please edit your question to include an example of the expected report based on sample data.

Comment: `Here is the expected result:` Thank you. However a `minimal reproducible example` include sample data. Would you please edit your question to include the sample data that you used to create the expected result.